# Uniswap Fee or how 180 AMPL tokens suddenly "disappeared" from blockchain

Tags: erc-20, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, transfer, defi

If you look  at https://etherscan.io/token/0xd46ba6d942050d489dbd938a2c909a5d5039a161?a=0xfe6c9c5a0d36eba3a767aaf6df2f335e666a74e7, you can notice that there were 3 transactions associated with the address `0xfe6c9c5a0d36eba3a767aaf6df2f335e666a74e7`.
And if you sum up the quantity `in` (*141,178604069* + *1659,518828706* = *1800,697432775*) and
subtract quantity `out` (*1800,697432775* - *1620,109104886*) there should stay *180,588327889* AMPL on the address.
But actually there is 0 AMPL. Just curious about it, how could that be done without emiting Transfer or Burn event on behalf of `0xfe6c9c5a0d36eba3a767aaf6df2f335e666a74e7` address? How can I track where *180,588327889* AMPL "disappeared"

The same thing happened in the second `in` [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x361546f754de1aec634ddfaa42a18b5744ff2c79f420db8b017d58d90b7e461b) : after sending *1659.518828706* to the address, the balance had to be equal to `1800,697432775` (balance was *141,178604069* before this transaction), but actual balance showing in that block is equal to `1747.184124201`

```sh
curl -XPOST https://mynode \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id":1,
    "method":"eth_call",
    "params":[{"to":"0xd46ba6d942050d489dbd938a2c909a5d5039a161", "data":"0x70a08231000000000000000000000000fe6c9c5a0d36eba3a767aaf6df2f335e666a74e7"},"0xa3496c"]
    }'

{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000196cc4a0129"
}
```

*196cc4a0129* is equal to *1747184124201* and AMPL's decimal is *9*, so the result is *1747.184124201*.
Please someone explain me where this amount of tokens "disappeared".

Comment: From their [docs](https://www.ampleforth.org/basics/) the balances are not fixed they adjust dynamically following price changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  But as far as I know every balance changing operation with tokens should be shown in the logs. Surprisingly, there are no any logs related to these changes.

Comment: Reading the contracts on Etherscan they do so in a global way when invoking the rebase function.